# installing package from a local .tar.gz file on Linux

Tags: r

I would like to install the `plyr` package from a .tar.gz file, into my library of R packages on a linux machine.  How would I go about doing this?  Do I just place it in the library directory?  What if I do not have write permissions?

Answer (score 34):

In the command line:

```
R CMD INSTALL <package-name>.tar.gz
```

Or in R:

```
install.packages(<pathtopackage>, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: please dont forget the quotes "".

Hence, it is  install.packages("<pathtopackage>", repos = NULL, type="source")


Thanks for sharing

Comment: I was getting the following error: "install: missing destination file operand after <package-name>.tar.gz"
This was resolved by typing "INSTALL" in CAPITAL LETTERS instead of just "install."

Answer (score 11):

From the command line,

```
R CMD INSTALL plyr_x.y.z.tar.gz
```

If you don't have permission to write to the standard library directory and can't use `sudo` to override, you can install it somewhere else via

```
R CMD INSTALL -l <user_lib> plyr_x.y.z.tar.gz
```

where `<user_lib>` is a directory you can write to.  You may need to specify `lib.loc` when subsequently loading the package, if `<user_lib>` is not in `.libPaths` (see @DWin's answer).

See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html for more information; `R CMD INSTALL --help` may also be useful, albeit terse.

Comment: +1 for pointer to the relevant manual.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have permissions to the default installed library you can add to the search path that R uses with `.libPaths` which "gets/sets the library trees within which packages are looked for."

```
.libPaths()  # will display all current libraries
?.libPaths
```

The second argument to `install.packages` (after the name of your `plyr.version.tar.gz` file) could be a user-controlled library directory.

```
?install.packages
```

I was a bit puzzled by first asking about installing from CRAN and then asking about installing a tar.gz file from which I formed the impression that you had already downloaded the file and were hoping to install it.