# Unable to install Tidyr on R v3.4.2 - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: r, installation, version, tidyr

I am trying to install the tydir R package on my Ubuntu machine (v. 16.04.3 LTS). I am using R version 3.4.2.

```
> install.packages("tidyr")

Installing package into '/home/rus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies 'purrr', 'tidyselect'

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_0.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 21101 bytes (20 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 20 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyr_0.7.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 369542 bytes (360 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 360 KB

ERROR: dependency 'purrr' is not available for package 'tidyselect'
* removing '/home/rus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyselect'
ERROR: dependencies 'purrr', 'tidyselect' are not available for package 'tidyr'
* removing '/home/rus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyr'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpWFaW85/downloaded_packages'
>
```

Seems the problem is caused by the purr package. I have done the same on a Windows 10 Computer and everything works fine. The only difference I see so far is the version. On Linux, it is trying to install purr_0.2.3 and in Windows purr_0.2.4

```
> install.packages("purrr")
Installing package into '/home/rus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror

Comment: Have you tried [installing from a local .tar.gz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940688/installing-package-from-a-local-tar-gz-file-on-linux)

Comment: I have download purrr_0.2.4.tar.gz but dont know how to proceed know

Comment: Just look at the top answer to the SO question @MichaelBird linked

Comment: Have you installed r-base-dev ( ```sudo apt-get install r-base-dev```)? Also you could try installing the Ubuntu package for purrr ```sudo apt-get install r-cran-purrr```

Comment: After  {sudo apt-get install r-base-dev} the output is Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base-dev is already the newest version (3.4.2-1xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After {sudo apt-get install r-cran-purrr} the output is Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r-cran-purr

Comment: Honestly though the Cran page shows 0.2.4 so maybe before going through all that trouble just try a different mirror

Comment: Could you let me know how to do that? I am sorry but i dont have lot of experince yet